# How to capture the texture of 8 mm semi precious stone bead?

Tags: photoshop, macro, product-photography

What method would you recommend me to use if I wanted to reconstruct in 3d semi precious beads ? Amethist, aghates, aquamarine ect with highly accurate results ? How am I suppose to get the texture from the bead knowing that the bead is only 4mm to 8mm in diameter ? Is the spherical shape gonna be too hard to deal with? Should I buy a super high resolution camera ?  how many Mega pixels should that camera be .. What software should I use ? What would you recommend me to do for best end result?

Please know that I am a complete novice , but I am willing to learn to be successfull in this project

Thanks

Amelie

Comment: What do you mean by "3d"?  What is your final output, a webpage?  Are you shooting a few, or hundreds? Lighting is just as important as the camera, you may want multiple off-camera flashes and light modifiers.

Comment: The camera doesn’t matter as much as the lens will in this case. You should look into macro lenses since they specialize in close up photography

Answer (score 1):

It's all basically a trade-off between sensors size and image quality. Large sensor sizes give a better image but are harder to work with.

If you want an 8mm bead to fill the frame, then on a DSLR you need a 3X magnification (full-frame) or 2x magnification (APS-C) because the sensor eight are respectively 24mm and 16mm. This is even worse for the 4mm beads: 6x or 4x). Other cameras (compacts, "bridges") have a smaller sensor, so don't require as much magnification, but AFAIK their unchangeable lens alone won't let you shoot close enough to even reach 1x. So, two general solutions:

#### High-end camera (DSLR or mirrorless)

There are lenses for extreme macro (for instance [this one](https://shop.usa.canon.com/shop/en/catalog/mp-e-65mm-f-28-1-5x-macro-photo)) but they aren't cheap. There are other techniques (lens reversal) but getting them working right is a hobby by itself. In all cases, at such magnifications, your depth of field is very shallow, you will never get the whole bead in focus, your will have to take several photos of the bead, focusing on "slices" and then uses an application that selected the part with the best focus from the series of photos to produce an image where everything is in focus. This is called "focus stacking".

#### Compact/super zoom

You can use a ["close-up" lens)(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close-up_lens). Some are decent (Raynox), but are of course not the less expensive of the lot. This could let you get close enough for your purposes, with the caveat that the image will possibly be a bit soft. You still need a camera with some "expert" features like manual focus, manual exposure, remote control, and possibly external flash control. You may still have to do focus stacking.

In all cases, you'll also have to consider other paraphernalia such as a stand, a focusing rail, external lighting, and something to rotate the bead in front of a lens if you want to capture the whole surface.

Answer (score 1):

Any modern camera will have more than enough pixels to meet your needs, especially if we’re just talking about web viewing. Take this image for example (my apologies on it being a screengrab from my phone. The OG is over the size limit and I’m unable to mess with it at this time):

[image]

That was shot with a 5Dmk2 at 21 megapixels. For my use cases, I go with a poor mans macro - extension tubes on a 70-200. Since this type of shooting will be your main job, I’d recommend a dedicated macro lens.

I’m not sure what you mean by “recreate in 3D.” If you mean to build a web app that allows people to build a string of beads and manipulate it to see the string from all different angles...well, I think you should contact a web developer for that one.

Oh, and the above was shot inside something called a light box - very important for even lighting. So, you need any modern camera, a dedicated macro lens, and a light box. That’s the easy stuff. Next, you need the skills to use them.

Answer (score 1):

For your needs, you don't need to go terribly overboard since you're looking for texture, not aesthetic image quality(unless i misunderstood you)

Here i took a shot just for you, using an old t3i, tamron 16-300@300, plus 68mm of inexpensive extension tubes, and an on camera speedlight with a big bounce card. cropped to 10mp. the opal i measured with a caliper at 3.15mm. ball point pen for reference.

The bounce card is key because at this close distance, the flash head cannot "see" the object when it's less than an inch from the lens.

stopping down is crucial, as focus becomes incredibly narrow with this setup. this shot was at f/16. there is a catch 22: diffraction occurs at smaller apertures which is a softening of the image, which may affect your textures.

Some fixed lens cameras may do a good macro, but i wouldn't bet on it without a first hand test.

[image]